# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while adding cookies in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am getting System.NullReferenceException when I am trying to add cookie. I made breakpoint to make sure about it. It was fine until adding the cookie in Response.Cookies. I think it occurs because of my html code. Here is below my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<a class="brand-logo center">@Html.ActionLink("Engish", "SetCulture", "Home", new { culture = "en-US" }, null)</a>
        <a class="brand-logo center">@Html.ActionLink("Deutsch", "SetCulture", "Home", new { culture = "de" }, null)</a>

public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{
    // Validate input
    culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
    // Save culture in a cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
    if (cookie != null)
        cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
    else
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
        cookie.Value = culture;
    }
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public static class CultureHelper
{
    // Valid cultures
    private static readonly List<string> _validCultures = new List<string> { "af", "af-ZA", "sq", "sq-AL", "gsw-FR", "am-ET", "ar", "ar-DZ", "ar-BH", "ar-EG", "ar-IQ", "ar-JO", "ar-KW", "ar-LB", "ar-LY", "ar-MA", "ar-OM", "ar-QA", "ar-SA", "ar-SY", "ar-TN", "ar-AE", "ar-YE", "hy", "hy-AM", "as-IN", "az", "az-Cyrl-AZ", "az-Latn-AZ", "ba-RU", "eu", "eu-ES", "be", "be-BY", "bn-BD", "bn-IN", "bs-Cyrl-BA", "bs-Latn-BA", "br-FR", "bg", "bg-BG", "ca", "ca-ES", "zh-HK", "zh-MO", "zh-CN", "zh-Hans", "zh-SG", "zh-TW", "zh-Hant", "co-FR", "hr", "hr-HR", "hr-BA", "cs", "cs-CZ", "da", "da-DK", "prs-AF", "div", "div-MV", "nl", "nl-BE", "nl-NL", "en", "en-AU", "en-BZ", "en-CA", "en-029", "en-IN", "en-IE", "en-JM", "en-MY", "en-NZ", "en-PH", "en-SG", "en-ZA", "en-TT", "en-GB", "en-US", "en-ZW", "et", "et-EE", "fo", "fo-FO", "fil-PH", "fi", "fi-FI", "fr", "fr-BE", "fr-CA", "fr-FR", "fr-LU", "fr-MC", "fr-CH", "fy-NL", "gl", "gl-ES", "ka", "ka-GE", "de", "de-AT", "de-DE", "de-LI", "de-LU", "de-CH", "el", "el-GR", "kl-GL", "gu", "gu-IN", "ha-Latn-NG", "he", "he-IL", "hi", "hi-IN", "hu", "hu-HU", "is", "is-IS", "ig-NG", "id", "id-ID", "iu-Latn-CA", "iu-Cans-CA", "ga-IE", "xh-ZA", "zu-ZA", "it", "it-IT", "it-CH", "ja", "ja-JP", "kn", "kn-IN", "kk", "kk-KZ", "km-KH", "qut-GT", "rw-RW", "sw", "sw-KE", "kok", "kok-IN", "ko", "ko-KR", "ky", "ky-KG", "lo-LA", "lv", "lv-LV", "lt", "lt-LT", "wee-DE", "lb-LU", "mk", "mk-MK", "ms", "ms-BN", "ms-MY", "ml-IN", "mt-MT", "mi-NZ", "arn-CL", "mr", "mr-IN", "moh-CA", "mn", "mn-MN", "mn-Mong-CN", "ne-NP", "no", "nb-NO", "nn-NO", "oc-FR", "or-IN", "ps-AF", "fa", "fa-IR", "pl", "pl-PL", "pt", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "pa", "pa-IN", "quz-BO", "quz-EC", "quz-PE", "ro", "ro-RO", "rm-CH", "ru", "ru-RU", "smn-FI", "smj-NO", "smj-SE", "se-FI", "se-NO", "se-SE", "sms-FI", "sma-NO", "sma-SE", "sa", "sa-IN", "sr", "sr-Cyrl-BA", "sr-Cyrl-SP", "sr-Latn-BA", "sr-Latn-SP", "nso-ZA", "tn-ZA", "si-LK", "sk", "sk-SK", "sl", "sl-SI", "es", "es-AR", "es-BO", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-CR", "es-DO", "es-EC", "es-SV", "es-GT", "es-HN", "es-MX", "es-NI", "es-PA", "es-PY", "es-PE", "es-PR", "es-ES", "es-US", "es-UY", "es-VE", "sv", "sv-FI", "sv-SE", "syr", "syr-SY", "tg-Cyrl-TJ", "tzm-Latn-DZ", "ta", "ta-IN", "tt", "tt-RU", "te", "te-IN", "th", "th-TH", "bo-CN", "tr", "tr-TR", "tk-TM", "ug-CN", "uk", "uk-UA", "wen-DE", "ur", "ur-PK", "uz", "uz-Cyrl-UZ", "uz-Latn-UZ", "vi", "vi-VN", "cy-GB", "wo-SN", "sah-RU", "ii-CN", "yo-NG" };

    // Include ONLY cultures you are implementing
    private static readonly List<string> _cultures = new List<string> {
        "en-US",  // first culture is the DEFAULT
        "de", // German NEUTRAL culture

    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the language is a right-to-left language. Otherwise, false.
    /// </summary>      
    public static bool IsRighToLeft()
    {
        return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a valid culture name based on "name" parameter. If "name" is not valid, it returns the default culture "en-US"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Culture's name (e.g. en-US)</param>
    public static string GetImplementedCulture(string name)
    {
        // make sure it's not null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture

        // make sure it is a valid culture first
        if (_validCultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() == 0)
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture if it is invalid


        // if it is implemented, accept it
        if (_cultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
            return name; // accept it

        // Find a close match. For example, if you have "en-US" defined and the user requests "en-GB", 
        // the function will return closes match that is "en-US" because at least the language is the same (ie English)  
        var n = GetNeutralCulture(name);
        foreach (var c in _cultures)
            if (c.StartsWith(n))
                return c;

        // else 
        // It is not implemented
        return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture as no match found
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns default culture name which is the first name decalared (e.g. en-US)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDefaultCulture()
    {
        return _cultures[0]; // return Default culture

    }

    public static string GetCurrentCulture()
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }

    public static string GetCurrentNeutralCulture()
    {
        return GetNeutralCulture(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    }


    public static string GetNeutralCulture(string name)
    {
        if (!name.Contains("-")) return name;

        return name.Split('-')[0]; // Read first part only. E.g. "en", "de"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add CultureHelper to question.

Comment: I have added my CultureHelper class

Comment: I think Cookies property or the Response object is null. This could happen depending on where you are calling this code. For example if you attempt to access the Response object in a background thread it might be null because there's no HttpContext associated to background threads.

Comment: I think my code is fine. The problem is may be in my html code. This is my html code where I am calling cookie values,
    <a class="brand-logo center">@Html.ActionLink("Engish", "SetCulture", "Home", new { LanguageAbbreviation = "en-US" }, null)</a>
            <a class="brand-logo center">@Html.ActionLink("Deutsch", "SetCulture", "Home", new { LanguageAbbreviation = "de" }, null)</a>

Comment: ِDoes NullReferenceException occures in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);?

Comment: Yes. It occurs in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Comment: Hi . Can you give me a suggestion how I can solve this problem in this line please? I can not get any idea.